# Using DAX with a SELECTEDVALUE From Slicer Not Working correctly

Tags: powerbi, dax, selectedvalue

I have a slicer which selects a username then using the Selected Value I want to compare this against a column in a table to set a Yes or No if its present within the Column. This is not working and always returns No, Although I know the SELECTEDVALUE is correct and has the value I need, if I try and interogate the value it always returns a blank

This is driving my crazy for something so simple, any help would be appreciated

UserFound =

IF(vwRptAlertRoles[General Manager] = SELECTEDVALUE(vwRptUserProfile[UserName]),"Yes","No")

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that part of the measure is returning multiple values for the vwRptAlertRoles[General Manager] item.

What you need to to is rather than check for =, check for IN:

```
UserFound = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(vwRptUserProfile[UserName) IN VALUES(vwRptUserProfile[UserName]), "Yes", "No")
```

VALUES returns a distinct list of item in that column that it can compare in the IN part.

Comment: This worked, Thanks so much for your help with this, its greatly appreciated.